# Invalid text value in SharePoint workflow 2013 string builder

Tags: sharepoint-designer, sharepoint-online, workflow

I have a text which is a letter template. This text contain workflow's variables and words. And when I start the workflow, it goes to stage where it creates the one-line string variable with this text and shows an error saying

> "Invalid text value"

. It worked with no errors when I removed all the words from text and leaved only the nine variables. But I need these words.

**UPDATE:**
Somehow I get to know that the substitutions lead to workflow crash if there is no spaces after them or if you pasted some words after them and these words gets underlined because the substitution is too close. I added two spaces, so the workflow not crashing. MS made these substitution that contains it's datatype inside.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally, found an answer by myself!
It was an action which make a record in workflow's journal. This action was writing a variable which value was "some long text. www.site-name.ru". Overall length of text value is 427. And workflow just crashes on that action.

Answer (score 1):

My guess is that you have a string that is too long. Try breaking it up into multiple variables if you can.

From: [Technet](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc262787.aspx#Workflow)

> Workflow variable value size 256 KB Boundary The maximum amount of
>   data that can be stored in a single workflow variable is 256 KB.
>   Exceeding this limit will cause the workflow instance to terminate.

Comment: Thank you but it's not that long.